# Is it really better to have an actual static file index.html that merely uses client JavaScript for Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I was watching multiple tutorials about how to present data on an actual webpage using Cloud Firestore. The thing is, everyone was using an actual index.html file sitting in Public folder(instead of serving html content within node.js code) and  tags which would mean that their program would use client-side JavaScript instead of node.js. But why? for what reason? According to Firebase tutorials and documentation, having an ACTUAL index.html sitting in Public folder is only for making static webpages, thus, if I'm making a complicated and dynamic webpage(which will also present Firestore data within the webpage), I should be using node.js right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase SDKs for Cloud Firestore perform [local persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) (caching) of doucments fetched from the database.  The persistence is enabled by default for Android and iOS, and you can programmatically enable it for web (currently experimental).  This local caching allows the client to avoid requesting documents from the server, which is obviously faster and cheaper than going through some API endpoint to request the data each time it's needed.

There is also the fact that the SDKs will push you [realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) of data as it changes on the server, as long as you have a listener attached to some document or query of interest.  You won't be able to duplicate this if you write it all in Cloud Functions.  You will spend a tremendous amount of time trying to duplicate and scale this behavior using socket.io or something similar on a backend you control.

You *could* write the entire app to be driven through API endpoints that you create.  There's nothing wrong with that, if it meets your needs.  But you'll write more code, you'll sacrifice realtime updates, and it will likely be slower and more expensive than allowing the client SDKs to optimize for you.

Comment: Because I'm a beginner, it was hard for me to understand the specific terms/concepts that you mentioned. So are you saying that if I'm making a dynamic webpage that presents lots of data from Firestore, it is recommended to have an actual index.html file sitting in Public(and use <script> tags to use client side JavaScript) rather than just having node.js files that would serve html contents within node.js code?

Comment: That's the standard practice, but you can do whatever you want that meets your particular requirements.